# Mutex lock a variable

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I'm searching a way to lock a variable in a C program. The fact is this variable is set in loop by a thread but in the other hand I have in my main an infinite loop who's reading this variable.

Is there anyway to perform this?

Comment: Maybe you don't need a full mutex - plain variables up to "machine word size" commonly do not need any locking at all (just adding the `volatile` modifier so that the compiler does not optimize access to them too much).

Comment: Like a boolean? who tell me if the variable is being acessed in read or write? Will it not do the same problem? I just want to be sure that the variable wont be access in read while the thread is writing in it.

Comment: On most common platforms you have a guarantee that a value up to certain size loaded from memory with a concurrently happening write operation will be either the old one or the new one, but nothing in between (like a few bits from the old, a few from the new). Though without memory barriers and because of the size limitation, the usefulness of this is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a mutex:

```
volatile int var=0;
pthread_mutex_t mtx=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

to read the variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
local_var=var;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
```

to set the variable:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
var=19;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
```

This would be what is needed if you are writing a threaded application - you have a pthreads tag.

Comment: I never heard anything about volatile variable thanks to you it works well